# Existence of a Common Tangent to a function

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

I want to prove that for a given smooth function $f:(0,\infty)\to (0,\infty)$ having two points of local minima and satisfying $\lim_{x\to 0,\infty} f(x)= \infty$. There exists at least a pair of points such that the line passing through them is a common tangent to the function.

**What I Tried**: As the graph of f is "W-shaped" it looks intuitively clear that it will happen but for a concrete proof I thought of applying LMVT but could not proceed further. Any hints will be helpful.

Regards

Comment: How "smooth" is your function? is it ${\cal C}^2$?

Comment: Although the texts doesn't mention it clearly, but you may assume it is twice continuously differentiable @TitoEliatron

Comment: I don't know if it's the fastest, but think about a function g that maps x to the y-intercept of the tangent line to the function at (x,f(x)).  If you can show that g is not injective, then you've got your two common points there.

Comment: I think you can tryy to apply Darboux property to $f'(x)$ taking into aacount that $\lim_{x\to 0}f'(x)=-\infty$